# Determine Segue Based on picker selection IOS, swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, picker

I have a picker with two options currently, and what I am looking for is, based on the selection made in the picker, to determine the next viewController below is what I tried to use however, I immediately got an error stating the last "if" statement should be converted into a let statement. Below is the code for my picker and attempt to lead into associated segue.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreData
import CoreLocation

class SchoolPickerViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var SchoolPicker: UIPickerView!
    let pickerData = ["Ohio State University", "University of Rochester"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SchoolPicker.dataSource = self
        SchoolPicker.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    @IBAction func schoolSelectorGoButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if pickerData = "Ohio State University" {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("ohioStateSelected", sender: sender)
        }
       if pickerData = "University of Rochester" {
           performSegueWithIdentifier("rochesterSelected", sender: sender)
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u should get selected picker data from Array

define

```
var selectedIndex = 0
```

then in this line

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? 
{
    selectedIndex = row
    return pickerData[row]
}
```

and in this action

```
@IBAction func schoolSelectorGoButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if pickerData[selectedIndex] == "Ohio State University" {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("ohioStateSelected", sender: sender)
    }
}
```